# How can i remove a large space underneath iframe html code?

Tags: html

This is the code.

```
<iframe 
        src="//cdn.bannersnack.com/banners/bzcso9jug/embed/index.html?userId=38586862&t=1546534170" 
        width="1200" 
        height="628" 
        scrolling="no" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allowtransparency="true" 
        allow="autoplay" 
        allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
```

Whenever i add the code to the website, the mobile version shows a large space underneath the html. (desktop shows fine.) Is there anything that could be causing this specifically for just the mobile version and not the desktop version? [i attached a screenshot to show what the mobile site looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qNsZ.jpg)

Comment: you should show use the related  code ..not the img (only)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, check [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to post your question.

Comment: Hm, could `height="628"` be "the problem"?

Comment: ^^^^ What he said, also most of those attributes [aren't html5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)